# Spring MVC 4.2 Jackson parse exception Unexpected character ('%' (code 37))

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm upgrading a Spring 3.1.x application to Spring 4.2.x. I've replaced all the jars, fixed any code/configuration issues and can now start the application. The problem comes in when posting JSON requests to my Spring controllers. I get the error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Using Chrome's developer tools, I can see the that the JSON request payload is, in fact, being sent over with ASCII characters, and the first character is a "%" sign. However, the ASCII-encoded string is valid JSON!

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/edge2/app/search/searchResults.ajax
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:968
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 07 Dec 2015 14:16:09 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:560
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=A1ED0AC2F3960170E9000FAB1E5FBD45
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/edge2/app/search.htm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
%7B%22quoteNumber%22%3A%22%22%2C%22quoteRevision%22%3A%22%22%2C%22createdDateBegin%22%3A%2209%2F07%2F2015%22%2C%22createdDateEnd%22%3A%22%22%2C%22quoteDescription%22%3A%22%22%2C%22productDescription%22%3A%22%22%2C%22productCategory%22%3A%22%22%2C%22customerName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22shipToName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contactLastName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22soldToNumber%22%3A%22%22%2C%22primarySales%22%3A%22%22%2C%22csrName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22materialNumber%22%3A%22%22%2C%22proposalStatus%22%3A%22REDY%22%2C%22proposalType%22%3A%22%22%2C%22userRole%22%3A%22Administrator%22%7D=
```

I don't have any customizations to the "standard" annotation-driven tag in my XML configuration. Here is what my controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchResults.ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<String> showSearchResults(@RequestBody SearchForm searchForm)
```

I have the Jackson libraries (2.6.3) in my classpath. Here is what the the Ajax request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "../app/search/searchResults.ajax",
data: JSON.stringify(getJSONForm()),
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
...
```

getJSONForm just creates a Javascript object and creates name/value pairs for the parameters.

Comment: I doubt that jackson tries to decode/unescape the ASCII-string before trying to deserialize the entity. There might be an annotation to put in your `SearchForm` to tell jackson to unescape the string before deserializing it.

Comment: Do you have a "processData" in your [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) settings? If not, that's probably the issue

Comment: @RC - Adding processData=false had no effect (default is true). It's still being sent over as an ASCII string, and getting the same error.

Comment: @Martin - I'd love if it *didn't* send the data in an ASCII string. Is there something I'm (accidentally) setting on the web side that's forcing it to send that way?

Comment: @BrianWaldhart my knowledge with frontend stuff like jquery is very limited, so im afraid i don't have any good suggestions. If all you're pages are setup for UTF-8 encoding (encoding have troubled me many times in the past), then i'm out of luck :/

Did you ensure that `getJSONForm` doesn't actually do this `ASCII` encoding?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, mark it so it could help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with the Json payload, I put your payload in a URLDecoder I got:

```
{"quoteNumber":"","quoteRevision":"","createdDateBegin":"09/07/2015","createdDateEnd":"","quoteDescription":"","productDescription":"","productCategory":"","customerName":"","shipToName":"","contactLastName":"","soldToNumber":"","primarySales":"","csrName":"","materialNumber":"","proposalStatus":"REDY","proposalType":"","userRole":"Administrator"}=
```

Notice the **=** character at the end of the payload.

In this site you can put your payload and get the decoded JSon String.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

I suggest you to try a call to your service from a RestClient like:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

or

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: Since my answer was deleted (not sure why), I will reluctantly accept this one, even though it didn't actually entirely solve the issue. Here's the text from my answer, which describes the *real*/core problem:

@Reos, your "=" character clue was crucial to figuring out what was going on.

In our app there is an $.ajaxPrefilter appending a "_cid" value to every Ajax request. As soon as I commented out that code, the request worked beautifully. Now I just need to figure out how to make it work with JSON data inputs.